# How to SortByColumns, Search, Filter in powerapps

Tags: search, powerapps

I got it to search for one column, but how to I add more items? ie "Material", "Destination",etc

SortByColumns(
Search(
Filter(
'Transfer Request',
"Not-Completed" in Putaway.Value
),
Search_SC.Text,
"Material"
),
"ID",
If(
SortDescending1,
Ascending,
Descending
)
)

Answer (score 0):

The Search function can search over multiple columns:

```
SortByColumns(
  Search(
    Filter( 'Transfer Request', "Not-Completed" in Putaway.Value ),
    Search_SC.Text,
    "Material", "Destination", "OtherColumn" ),
  "ID",
  If( SortDescending1, SortOrder.Ascending, SortOrder.Descending ) )
```

Comment: Is there a different way to do this if it is using a choice column vs a single line text column?

Comment: The Search function only works with text columns; you can use the [Filter function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-filter-lookup) with choice columns.